# Replicate tables or use multiple Entity Framework models

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have a bit of a beginner question.

My situation is we have multiple databases, one per application. The issue is some of the applications require data from the other databases.

So I'm slightly conflicted between should I:

1. Create a new table `z` into database 2 which is the same as table `x` in database 1 and replicate data

or

2. Create an Entity Framework model for each database in my application

Both seem to be doing rework but I somehow feel creating extra Entity Framework models is better as then I'm not repeating data in multiple databases.

Comment: with no more information, I would say, use two different CONTEXTs. For example one for an application domain, and another for an authentication layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely NOT create two table and try to replicate the data.  That would just be creating an on-going headache.

If both apps use some of the same tables you could create a `base` context containing the shared tables, then create an application specific subclass of the context for each application.  That would help avoid the duplicate code.

Comment: You'd have to have a separate context for the shared tables: one context can't access two databases.